# how to write Onload function using angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

i am using angular 4 check box tree structure,i want to know
how to write onload function in angular 4?

**ang.component.ts**

This is my component for tree view

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeViewComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-ng-navigations';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-checkboxes',   
    templateUrl: './checkboxes.component.html'
})
export class CheckboxesComponent {
    //@ViewChild('samples')
    constructor() {
    }  
    public countries: Object[] = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Australia', hasChild: true, expanded: true },
        { id: 2, pid: 1, name: 'New South Wales', isChecked: true },
        { id: 3, pid: 1, name: 'Victoria' },
        { id: 4, pid: 1, name: 'South Australia' },
        { id: 6, pid: 1, name: 'Western Australia', isChecked: true },
        { id: 7, name: 'Brazil', hasChild: true },
        { id: 8, pid: 7, name: 'Paraná' },
        { id: 9, pid: 7, name: 'Ceará' },
        { id: 10, pid: 7, name: 'Acre' },
        { id: 11, name: 'China', hasChild: true },
        { id: 12, pid: 11, name: 'Guangzhou' },
        { id: 13, pid: 11, name: 'Shanghai' },
        { id: 14, pid: 11, name: 'Beijing' },
        { id: 15, pid: 11, name: 'Shantou' },
        { id: 16, name: 'France', hasChild: true },
        { id: 17, pid: 16, name: 'Pays de la Loire' },
        { id: 18, pid: 16, name: 'Aquitaine' },
        { id: 19, pid: 16, name: 'Brittany' },
        { id: 20, pid: 16, name: 'Lorraine' },
        { id: 21, name: 'India', hasChild: true },
        { id: 22, pid: 21, name: 'Assam' },
        { id: 23, pid: 21, name: 'Bihar' },
        { id: 24, pid: 21, name: 'Tamil Nadu' },
        { id: 25, pid: 21, name: 'Punjab' }
    ];
    public field: Object = {
        dataSource: this.countries,
        id: 'id',
        parentID: 'pid',
        text: 'name',
        hasChildren: 'hasChild'
    };
    public showCheckBox: boolean = true;
    public checkedNodes: string[] = ['2', '6'];
}
```

**ang.component.html:**
This is my tree view structure using check boxes

```
 <p>Angular 4 Checkbox Tree</p>
    <div id='treeparent'>
        <ej-treeview id='treeelement' [fields]='field'
            [showCheckBox]='showCheckBox'> </ej-treeview>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're looking for ngOnInit which is normally used to setup things before the view loads. You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

simple example:

```
export class Example implements OnInit{
 constructor(){}

 ngOnInit(){
 //code that will execute at the start of the loading process
 }
}
```

Comment: one more doubt sir how to pass id angular 4 to  spring boot controller?

Comment: I'm assuming you have something like this.http.get(url) or .post(url), usually you just pass the id in the function and concatenate it to the url

getSpecific(id){
 this.http.get(url + id) ..
}

Comment: ok sir....@akirus         how to get database column id by using spring boot in angular 4 ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I'd suggest looking through https://angular.io/guide/http to get a better idea of how to communicate with your spring api.